# Can we get partial set of data from two different partitions in oracle?

Tags: c

If a table is partitioned by month and will there be any error while retrieving the data from 15th of previous month to 15th of the current month as data is spread across two different partitions.

Comment: If an error has occurred, then please include the number and error message in the question.

Comment: This was asked in an interview and interviewer didn't even explain it once asked later.

Comment: Why would there be any error?

Answer (score 2):

Crappy interview question, but the answer is No, ie, you can span partitions with queries without any issues:

```
SQL> create table t (   x date )
  2  partition by range ( x )
  3  (
  4    partition p1 values less than ( date '2018-05-01' ),
  5    partition p2 values less than ( date '2018-06-01' ),
  6    partition p3 values less than ( date '2018-07-01' )
  7  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into t
  2  select date '2018-04-01'+ rownum
  3  from dual
  4  connect by date '2018-04-01'+ level < date '2018-07-01';

90 rows created.

SQL>
SQL> select count(*) from t partition ( p1 ) ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        29

1 row selected.

SQL> select count(*) from t partition ( p2 ) ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        31

1 row selected.

SQL> select count(*) from t partition ( p3 ) ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        30

1 row selected.

SQL>
SQL> select count(*)
  2  from t
  3  where x between date '2018-05-15' and date '2018-06-15';

  COUNT(*)
----------
        32
```